# mail(): SMTP server response: 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address

Tags: php, email, plesk

Just recently and by accident, I found out that I cannot send emails to foreign sources beyond my server (I've been testing it with local Email addresses being installed at the same server). This is my code and I cannot send to (e.g.) gmail or yahoo.

```
$receiver = $emailadr;
$subj     = 'Auth';
$msg      = 'Thank you!';
$header = 'From: sometestmail@somedomain.com' . "\r\n" . 
'Reply-To: sometestmail@somedomain.com' . "\r\n" . 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
mail($receiver, $subj, $msg, $header);
```

When (attempting) sending, it comes up with this:

> :  mail(): SMTP server response: 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.

I'm using Plesk 12.5

Comment: So you know what the problem is. How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory to me. What do you want us to do about it?

Answer (score 3):

Error message is quite clear `This mail server requires authentication`

You can create mail user in Plesk and use following PHP class to send mail with authentication:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial#2

Also you can try some cloud mail services like http://sendgrid.com/ they have nice PHP API library.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem of the mailserver. Your codes is on a shared hosting? Your provider probably has an anti-spam configuration (hopefully). You have to make sure that your sender address is existing. For testing, it's also helpful if you send the message to yourself (if you didn't already), this has more chances to work and then you can check the mail headers.

On a average configured e-mail server, there are four ways of mail communication: (i assume your server is running somedomain.com and is providing @somedomain.com mails)

- Incoming: Mails from not-@somedomain.com to @somedomain.com. These mails are normally simply accepted.
- Outgoing: Mails from @somedomain.com to not-@somedomain.com. There mails are accepted if the origin IP address is in the local network (or the webserver). **That's what you want**
- Internal: Mails from @somedomain.com to @somedomain.com. That's another option for you, if you send the message to yourself. Here you have the highest change that the mail arrives
- Relay: Mails from not-@somedomain.com to not-@somedomain.com. This is what your server thinks you are doing. Relaying mails is **normally denied except for authenticated users** because it's normally spam (and that's what it tells you in the error message). Unfortunately, the standard PHP sendmail function doesn't support authentication. Because of this, you need to add the sender address to the mailserver's whitelist or (easier:) change it to an accepted internal address which changes your mail to an outgoing or internal one, depending on the receiver address.

Comment: so this email mustnt be non existent?

Comment: @MRXI I don't understand the question. PHP sends the mail using the sendmail command on the server. The server has an email server and this mailserver is returning the answer "503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address". The message tells you (freely translated) that the message is not accepted because sender and/or receiver address are not accepted. Both addresses are part of your PHP command

Comment: @DanielAlder: That is incorrect. The message says that the server requires authentication, meaning that the server requires authentication. It's as simple as that. It's a basic and commonplace security measure to prevent SMTP servers from being used as open relays to send spam. You have to be _authenticated_ to use it. You have to be a user, _authenticated_ on that system, to be trusted to send mail. It has nothing to do with the sender address.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Half true: It says you need authentication for sending to a non-local e-mail address. That is because it thinks that the mails already comes from outside and should be forwarded to another remote address (relay). But as a PHP application on the same server, it's normally ok to match the outgoing address to the local system, so that the mail is not a **relay** but an **outgoing** message. For this case you normally don't need authentication (which PHP doesn't support)

Comment: @DanielAlder: I would _never_ allow sending mail through my SMTP servers, either as initiator or a relay in a chain, without authentication. From a script or otherwise. I don't know anybody who would. It doesn't really matter whether PHP's `mail` function supports it, anyway, as it has not been fit for purpose for almost a decade. Spam filters are too good. You need a proper mail sending library that can form headers properly and do all the needful to make your email look like a genuine, honest email from the 21st century. Otherwise nobody's going to see it outside of their junk mail anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What's your problem? sendmail is a command, not an open port. Sending mail without authentication in this case means sending it through a pipe or 127.0.0.1, not the net. And I recommend in my answer to use a proper origin address in the same way as you recommend it in your comment. But if you really block your server so much that everything needs authentication, you will probably miss system information about errors in crons and backups or a broken raid etc.

Comment: @DanielAlder: We can continue this discussion when you are prepared to entertain it without statements like "what's your problem".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95172/discussion-between-daniel-alder-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: Ok, without using these three words: Did you ever see a server which has authentication for mails which are sent directly on the server itself using sendmail? I'm speaking about `echo "here is the mail" | sendmail root`. You write that you use authentication for this scenario? What mailserver software do you use?